# C# delegate properties

Tags: c#

Is it possible to pass a property as a delegate in c#?

I know that in C# we can pass functions as arguments to a method, But I have a property which in my situation is not much different than a function that takes no parameters, how can I pass it as an argument?

```
public IWebElement Name => _element.FindElements(By.ClassName("field-key"))[0].FindElements(By.TagName("label"))[0];
```

I'm working with selenium and changing elements. That's the reason why my `Name` property is the way it is. So I always get the latest name when I do something like: `MultinationalPage.GeneralPanel.DefinitionField.Name`.

In my test to prevent getting Stale Element Reference Exception, I use `Thread.Sleep()`, I know there are better ways, however, for now, this is my approach.

```
Thread.Sleep(5000)

multinational.EditModal.StateTracker.VerifyChanges(_multinational.GeneralPanel.DefinitionField.Name);
```

I would like to do the `Thread.Sleep(5000)` inside the `VerifyChanges()` that's why I want to pass the `Name` property as a delegate to `VerifyChanges(MultinationalPage.GeneralPanel.DefinitionField.Name)`.

Something like this:

```
public void VerifyChanges(Func<IWebElement> Name) 
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000)
    var name = Name;
    ...
}
```

Comment: cant you pass an action that calls the property?

Comment: You could pass a function as an argument, suplying the getter method to it. Or a pair of functions if you want to read/write.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: "But I have a property which in my situation is not much different than a function that takes no parameters" A property is different in that way, that it is actually **two** methods. Thus you´d need two delegates as well, one for getting, one for setting the value.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a better way to solve this problem.

Create an interface:

```
interface IHasName
{
    IWebElement Name { get; }
}
```

Implement:

```
class YourClass : IHasName
{
    public IWebElement Name
        => _element.FindElements(By.ClassName("field-key"))[0].FindElements(By.TagName("label"))[0];
}
```

Then your method:

```
public void VerifyChanges(IHasName hasName) 
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000)
    var name = hasName.Name;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to encapsulate the access to property in a lambda :

```cs
multinational.EditModal.StateTracker.VerifyChanges(
    () => _multinational.GeneralPanel.DefinitionField.Name
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can share your full code then we can have a better understanding of the problem that you are trying to solve. Passing a property is the same as passing a parameter value to a function. e.g. Lets us assume your function looks like

```
public void MyFunction(IWebElement webElement)
{
  // Your code goes here.
}
```

You can call this function and pass the property as follows:

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
MyFunction(obj.Name);
```

I assumed that MyClass is the name of the class which has this property.

======== Edited
In you case you can wrap your code inside a Func as follows

```
 public void VerifyChanges(() => multinational.GeneralPanel.DefinitionField.Name);
```